# iOS - "multiple build commands for output file" - can someone help me debug this?

Tags: ios4

I think I've tied my first project in a bit of a knot, by linking to an image that wasn't in the main folders structure but located somewhere else - in trying to straighten that out I'm now getting these warnings:

```
[WARN]Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/davebennett/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/The_Dogs-djvmthbassvcpifzucvcjpgktemi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GBGB.app/dashboard-button.png
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of how to track these down and deal with them?

Thanks

Comment: 've actually found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718246/xcode-strange-warning-multiple-build-commands-for-output-file - seems I needed to clear the references to the files which were in the wrong place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heyyy the answer is very simple..

See Xcode,

And then click the Build phases tab,then go to the "Copy Bundle Resources" And search for this image file name which showed in error warning message. If you see multiple entries for same file, delete the duplicate file.

Now build it, you will see the warning is removed..