# XCode warning - duplicate CMakeLists.txt while trying to change project name

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone, project

I tried to change the name of my xcode project, (which uses the cocos2d framework), but for some reason my main files folder (the one that contains all the .h and .mm files) wouldn't change the name. so then i manually clicked under "MyProj TARGETS -> Build Settings" and manually changed the fields:

1. Info.plist File
2. Header Search Paths
3. User Header Search Paths
4. Prefix Header

to be using "MyProj/" instead of "PrevName/" (the previous name i had named the project) but now i'm getting these two strange warnings:

```
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProj-fzlkaghtvjzkgkenbpejhzwvxsft/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyProj.app/CMakeLists.txt
Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'MyProj/Resources/Info.plist'.
```

you'll see that this is also mentioned under: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/33245  but no one has answered this part

and i tried to look under [Xcode warning: "Multiple build commands for output file"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718246/xcode-strange-warning-multiple-build-commands-for-output-file)   to see under "Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resource"... and indeed, there were 2 CMakeLists.txt files. one is:

```
MyProj/libs/Box2D
```

and the other is:

```
MyProj/libs/kazmath/src
```

which one do i need? or do i need both, since i think xcode used to be compiling with both??

i should mention that my project *seems* to be running okay right now if i leave the warnings in. but i don't like warnings that i don't understand, and i know that i *could* just swap my source/assets to a new project to get rid of the warning, but i'd like to know for future reference how to properly rename everything in a xcode project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh wow... I had no idea the traffic on stackoverflow is so low these days...(or at least for xcode & iOS dev)  *sighs*

Anyways, I *think* I figured out a fix.

I read [apple developer guilde](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2009/qa1649.html) for the second Warning

For the first Warning, I looked at another file that I had created, and I compared my project's settings to the other project's settings. (such a simple solution, duh, why didn't I think of this >_<) and it turns out, under `Copy Bundle Resources`, you're only supposed to have:

1. Your .png files and other resources used in code (but NOT your plist file, for the very reason given in the link above)
2. iTunesArtwork
3. ChangeLog

Actually, i'm not sure if you even need #2 or #3. I'll give an `upvote` to whoever experiments with it. So.... the solution is to simply remove all those other `CMakeLists` and `cmakes` and all that junk, including `plist` :)

Comment: *Oh wow... i had no idea the traffic on stack overflow is so low these days...(or at least for xcode & iOS dev) sighs* probably due to poor tagging: xcode is just an IDE, not a framework or a language. the framework is called cocoa-touch and the language objective-c. both would be much better tags, as we write code in objective-c and work with cocoa-touch.

Comment: ah, thank you!!! coming from an Android background, i hardly heard of cocoa-touch, so thanks for mentioning that one. as for the tag objective-c, i normally do tag in it. but i thought this particular question was more set-up oriented so that's why i tagged it xcode. thanks for fixing the tags