# iPhone @1x artwork 'multiple build' errors

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiimage

I've just added the `@1x` artwork to my iPhone app but I'm getting `'Multiple build commands for output file'` for each piece of `@2x` artwork. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Did you saw this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2747727/1091539

Comment: I did, but the answers they gave all involved deleting the duplicated files - surely I need to keep both my 1x and 2x artwork??

Comment: only retina artwork needs to be has @2x

Comment: Only my retina artwork is prefixed with '@2x', do I have to put 1x and 2x artwork in separate places?

Answer (score 0):

only check the required resource file for required target only