# In Xcode 4.6.2 iOS I'm getting 3 Dependency Analysis Multiple Buildd Command Warnings. Why?

Tags: xcode4

```
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Plastic-elbkklqplllhcmbttzpcwqphwnvn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Plastic.app/Default@2x.png
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Plastic-elbkklqplllhcmbttzpcwqphwnvn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Plastic.app/Default.png
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/Peter/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Plastic-elbkklqplllhcmbttzpcwqphwnvn/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Plastic.app/Default-568h@2x.png
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this resources copied into bundle more than once during build phase. Look for answers here: [Xcode warning: "Multiple build commands for output file"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2718246/2650588)