# ios app duplicated license: how is it built

Tags: ios, xcode

Got error message while trying to install app on my test phone, after importing cocoa pods:

> Multiple build commands for output file /Users/john/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/targetname-clmvbjcnurhbdsgnpyqpjpjerzvl/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/targetname.app/LICENSE

I am guessing xcode is complaining about some build settings for license? If so, where in xcode is license generated? When I looked in the license file, it is just some Appache license agreement boilerplate text file...

I tried to remove the LICENSE referred and it still did not work...

BTW the same setting worked on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

you might have several files in your project that have the same name. You just have to delete or rename the files with duplicate names and the problem is solved

[there is the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718246/xcode-warning-multiple-build-commands-for-output-file)