# xCode 13 Build issue with iOS App Clip Extension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode13, ios-extensions

I have migrated from Xcode 12.4 to Xcode 13.2. My App is having App Clip extension bundled. My App and App Clip Extension having one framework i.e. FrameworkA. It's separately copied to both targets, name is same but size is different due to AppClip limited size.

It was working fine in Xcode 12.4 but in Xcode 13 it's giving below error
and warning -

> duplicate output file ..... on task: ProcessXCFramework .....

Error - Multiple commands produce

1. > Command: Process XCFramework /Users/abc/Testapp/TestAppClip/FrameworkA.xcframework /Users/deriveddata/TestAppsdfsdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FrameworkA.framework no simulator
2. > Command: Process XCFramework /Users/abc/Testapp/TestApp/FrameworkA.xcframework /Users/deriveddata/TestAppsdfsdf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FrameworkA.framework no simulator

Comment: try these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718246/xcode-warning-multiple-build-commands-for-output-file

Comment: @ChanOnly123 Thanks for suggestion but that is from xcode 4. This is different issue which started occuring in xcode 13